# ¿Cómo manejar un mismo repositorio git en tres lugares distintos?

Tags: git, github, hosting

Mi escenario es el siguiente:

1. Un **sitio web remoto** alojado en hosting compartido (Bluehost)
2. Mi **dispositivo local**, con sistema operativo Linux (Ubuntu)
3. La web de **github.com**

Ahora mi intención es crear una aplicación web usando [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) para desplegarla en mi sitio web remoto (1) y **poder editar los archivos de ese proyecto preferentemente en mi dispositivo local** (2), al mismo tiempo quiero tener una copia del proyecto en github.com (3).

Esto es lo que tengo ahorma mismo:

Creé el repositorio en mi sitio web, y luego `push` del mismo a la web de github (3). Hasta ese punto todo está OK, tengo los archivos en mi sitio web y en github.com. Para hacer alguna prueba, modifiqué un archivo directamente en (3) y luego, desde (1) hice un `pull` correctamente, el archivo modificado en github.com se actualizó también en mi servidor remoto.

En mi equipo local todavía no hay nada y es ahí donde surgen mis dudas, que son básicamente dos:

1. ¿Cómo puedo normalizar todo esto para poder trabajar preferentemente desde mi equipo local? ¿Debo hacer un `clone` desde mi servidor o desde github.com?
2. ¿Cómo mantendría el código actualizado en los tres lugares? Por ejemplo, modifiqué el archivo `X` en mi equipo local, ¿de qué modo reflejo esos cambios tanto en el servidor remoto como en la web de github?

Generalmente los repositorios se trabajan desde dos lugares según tengo entendido, pero aquí tenemos tres escenarios y quisiera saber en estos casos cuál sería la manera de proceder. No estoy buscando opiniones, sino preguntando por algún tipo de práctica o norma con respecto a git para manejar este tipo de escenarios.

**NOTAS:**

1. Este respositorio no tiene colaboradores, ni es para trabajo en equipo, soy el único usuario que hará cambios en él, de hecho es un repositorio privado.
2. Los archivos que tengo creados ahora son de prueba, si hace falta modificar algo, o crear el repositorio original desde cero en algún otro lugar concreto, podría hacerlo partiendo desde cero.

Comment: Git es de naturaleza distribuida, de tal manera que la centralización puede ser prácticamente como quieras; basta con seleccionar un host/repositorio/rama de la cantidad de combinaciones que te imagines: tres repositorios en un solo host, un repositorio con tres ramas en un solo host, o como en tu planteamiento inicial: tres hosts, un repo por host, con una rama master por repo. Hemos visto ramas nombradas como: CaracteristicaX, Juan, Principal, Pruebas, Desarrollo y la clásica Master, pudiendo jalar/empujar desde/hacia cualquiera.

Comment: Cabe mencionar que hay [cierto debate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45452/is-using-git-for-deploying-a-bad-practice) sobre usar git como herramienta de despliegue, principalmente por cuestiones de seguridad; de hecho, vemos muy frecuentemente ataques hacia esas vulnerabilidades.

Comment: @Sal muy interesante lo que se debate en esa pregunta/respuestas ... Tengo que ver con calma cada cosa y luego tomar una decisión, gracias por tu enfoque que me abre otra ventana con un panorama también desconocido. En un tutorial indicado más abajo en comentarios se explica cómo usar `post-receive` para crear el directorio `.git` fuera del directorio público del sitio y hacer que el contenido se cree en la carpeta destinada al sitio web, resolviendo así ese problema de seguridad.

Answer (score 3):

Me dí varias vueltas redactando esta respuesta y no creo haber llegado a algo coherente. Por el contrario, se me van abriendo ramificaciones. Pero, por favor, deja todas las preguntas que estimes necesarias para que este texto tome una forma que sea útil a la larga.

---

Hay muchos flujos posibles para trabajar con GIT en el escenario que describes, en donde se reconocen 3 partes. Propongo que les llamemos:

1. Tu **working copy** o **local** o **copia local** (tú le llamaste **2**)
2. El **upstream** o **remoto** (github, codedeploy, gitlab, bitbucket, etc) (tú le llamaste **3**)
3. El **host** ,**servidor** o **deploy server** donde se disponibiliza la aplicación o servicio (tú le llamaste **1**)

*tanto tu local como el servidor en bluehost son, en rigor, working copies, pero tienen roles distintos en un flujo estable de trabajo*

[image: Flujo GIT local - github - deploy]

Fuente: [Git Workflow](https://business-science.github.io/shiny-production-with-aws-book/git-workflow.html)

Aunque cada working copy de cada desarrollador puede salvar la patria haciendo de respaldo de emergencia (si fuese necesario), y aunque a nivel de diseño GIT sea un sistema descentralizado, eso no significa que se trabaje en una red P2P entre desarrolladores. Se puede, pero es muy difícil de gobernar y no ofrece ventajas prácticas. Al final en GIT igual se trabaja como al lado izquierdo:

[image: Al final no es tan distinto...]

Fuente: [SG-Dev](http://sgdev-blog.blogspot.com/2014/03/using-git.html)

En términos generales, las copias locales de los desarrolladores empujan código hacia el remoto (push) y se traen código desde él (pull) usándolo como un pivote para propagar los cambios con el resto del equipo. Los desarrolladores no tienen cómo empujar código directo a la copia local de un compañero ni leer el código que éstos tengan a medio editar en un momento dado. Ambas cosas serían medio invasivas. Tanto en la colaboración de un equipo formal como en las grandes iniciativas de código abierto, lo que haces es disponibilizar tus cambios en el upstream para que otro desarrollador haga algo con ellos: los integre, los descargue a su local, o te deje un comentario cruel, por ejemplo. **GIT es un sistema de control de versiones. Github es una plataforma de colaboración** que va mucho más allá del mecanismo o algoritmo en uso.

En tu caso de uso eres el único desarrollador, sí. Pero el servidor de deploy, Bluehost, es una working copy. El modelo de 3 actores se puede entender como un modelo de más de un desarrollador.

---

#### Preguntas Puntuales

> ¿Cómo puedo normalizar todo esto para poder trabajar preferentemente desde mi equipo local?

No hay normas, sí convenciones. En general, éstas buscan ordenar los pasos que van desde tu local al software productivo, dado que mientras más caminos haya sobre la mesa más difícil es gestionarlos. Adicionalmente, diría yo, es sano plantearse que todos los componentes y actores tienden a seguir una misma dirección. Por ejemplo, que  todo cambio se hace en tu local, se sube a github y cuando corresponde se deploya en bluehost. No pasa como en tu experimento en que el host te manda commits de vuelta.

Para que esa idea, aunque ingenua, se cumpla, tienes algunas directivas tácticas que más o menos debieran respetarse:

- En tu local se asume que no hay otras fuentes de modificaciones en el código, por lo que al sincronizar, ante la duda, tu local será la fuente de verdad.
- En el deploy server, al contrario, se asume que lo que contenga el upstream en la rama productiva (en este momento, la única rama, claro) es fidedigno y siempre puedo traérmela (con un git pull) y quedar parado en una versión funcional. Ante la duda, el server nunca es la fuente de verdad
- En el upstream (github) no se hacen cambios directamente. Github tiene settings para custodiar esa condición, y es sano obligarse uno mismo a no pushear directamente a master tampoco, sino siempre en branches. De esa manera el código siempre llega a master mediante una transacción reversible y no un CTRL+S del que nos arrepentimos toda la semana.

Es un modelo ingenuo porque en realidad, con frecuencia, sí habrá cambios en el upstream. Por ejemplo, cada vez que se haga merge entre ramas, cuando no se pueda hacer un fast forward. Siendo el único desarrollador te pasará menos, pero te pasará. Esos merge dan, de por sí, origen a un commit que está en el upstream y tienes que traer a tu local para quedar al día.

Para que el modelo anterior funcione, y máxime si hay varios devs, es necesario sacar provecho de las ramas. Para ello, de nuevo, hay convenciones, y la más exitosa, aunque está un poco vetusta, [es gitflow: "A Successfull GIT branching model"](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Lo pongo como referencia de una implementación real y longeva del concepto de "una sola dirección"

Hay otro escenario donde es correcto que existan cambios en el upstream y no en tu local, que es cuando el pipeline productivo involucra una etapa que solamente se usará en el servidor de deploy. Por ejemplo, que luego de un commit a master se gatille una serie de pruebas, y si pasan con éxito, se crea una rama efímera y un commit sobre ella, firmado por Gastón Github, el dueño, y esa es la rama que se deploya en bluehost. La próxima vez que quieras deployar todo rastro de esa rama accesoria se pisará con el nuevo deploy, que viene de la única fuente de verdad. Este es un caso rebuscado y solamente cobra sentido después de muchas horas mirando a webpack holgazanear.

Con respecto a tus preguntas

> Creé el repositorio en mi sitio web, y luego push del mismo a la web de github (3). Hasta ese punto todo está OK, tengo los archivos en mi sitio web y en github.com.

Desde cualquier working copy puedes hacer lo mismo, pero no llegará a tu local si no hay un `git pull` de por medio. En lo que no sea simple ejercicio o prueba de concepto, es mejor evitar cambios en el servidor de deploy, que está pensado para creerle al upstream, no para escribir de vuelta en éste.

> Para hacer alguna prueba, modifiqué un archivo directamente en (3) y luego, desde (1) hice un pull correctamente, el archivo modificado en github.com se actualizó también en mi servidor remoto.

En general, el servidor remoto tenderá a equipararse con lo que sea que tenga el upstream al ejecutar un deploy. Básicamente el mismo ejercicio que hiciste salvo porque el cambio del párrafo anterior provino de tu local.

> ¿Debo hacer un clone desde mi servidor o desde github.com?

El único upstream es github. Tu servidor en bluehost es una working copy igual que tu local sólo que para un uso específico.

> ¿Cómo mantendría el código actualizado en los tres lugares? Por ejemplo, modifiqué el archivo X en mi equipo local, ¿de qué modo reflejo esos cambios tanto en el servidor remoto como en la web de github?

En tu local commiteas el cambio y pusheas a github.  En bluehost el siguiente pull se equipara con github y todos quedan con el archivo en la versión que tú editaste.

Yendo más atrás, voy a relatar toda la secuencia desde que se crea el repo hasta sugerir un deploy

#### Flujo muy básico local / upstream / deploy

Supongamos que creas un repo vacío en Github (que será el **remoto**). El servicio te da la URL del remoto con algunas instrucciones básicas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siguiendo esas instrucciones, clonas el remoto dando lugar a tu copia local:

```
 acedano@local$ git clone git@github.com:ffflabs/repo-vacio.git
 acedano@local$ cd repo-vacio
 acedano@local$ echo '# Primer Commit' >> README.md
 acedano@local$ git commit README.md -m 'agrega título al README'
```

Pero también puedes pararte en un directorio existente e inicializarlo como repo

```
 acedano@local$  cd directorio-existente
 acedano@local$  git init
 acedano@local$  git remote add origin  git@github.com:ffflabs/repo-vacio.git
 acedano@local$  echo '# Primer Commit' >> README.md
 acedano@local$  git commit README.md -m 'agrega título al README'
```

En este caso yo le dije al repo que añadiera un remoto (git remote add) con el sobrenombre `origin` apuntando a `git@github.com:ffflabs/repo-vacio.git`. Aunque suena como si `origin` tuviera un significado especial, *no lo tiene*. Es una convención y podría haber usado `remoto_cualquiera`

```
acedano@local$  git remote add remoto_cualquiera git@github.com:ffflabs/repo-vacio.git
```

---

#### Trabajas en Local > Pusheas al remoto

Los archivos que vas añadiendo a tu copia local, no sólo físicamente sino al control de versiones (mediante `git add <archivo>`) y luego commiteas, eventualmente querrás subirlos al remoto

```
 acedano@local$ git add --all # más vale que antes hayas puesto vendor en el .gitignore
 acedano@local$ git commit -am "commiteando todo"
 acedano@local$ git push -u origin master
```

Ese último git push, al ser el primero, lleva la indicación de usar como upstream (-u) el remoto `origin` (que ya dijimos podría tener cualquier sobrenombre) y su rama `master` (que también es una convención).  Los commits sucesivos seguramente podrás hacerlos con `git push` y ya.

---

#### Deploy en el Servidor

En algún momento habrás creado o crearás una copia de tu repo en el servidor.

```
 acedano@local$ ssh ubuntu@bluehost

 ubuntu@bluehost$ cd /var/www
 ubuntu@bluehost$ git clone git@github.com:ffflabs/repo-vacio.git
 ubuntu@bluehost$ cd /repo-vacio
 ubuntu@bluehost$ composer install # y editar algún archivo config o .env
```

Y esa copia la irás actualizando cuando estimes que es hora de "**deployar**" un nuevo release. Cada vez que deployes un release, la secuencia será más o menos

```
 acedano@local$ git commit -am "Listo para producción"
 acedano@local$ git push
 acedano@local$ ssh ubuntu@bluehost

 ubuntu@bluehost$ cd /var/www/repo-vacio
 ubuntu@bluehost$ git pull
 ubuntu@bluehost$ composer install
 ubuntu@bluehost$ sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
```

---

#### Una sola fuente de verdad

En el mundo ideal el código correcto a deployar es simplemente una actualización encima de lo que deployaste la última vez. Como nada es tan fácil en la realidad, pasa a menudo que pequeñas diferencias resultan en incompatibilidades. Por lo mismo una práctica sana (aunque no escrita a fuego) es que

> **la rama master del remoto siempre debe estar "deployable"**

O sea, que sin importar la ensalada que tenga en mi local, no debo contaminar la rama master de github sino usar branches

Aunque probablemente te encontrarás que alguna parte del flujo modificó la copia de trabajo en bluehost y no te dejará hacer `git pull`. Será más sano forzar la copia de trabajo para quedar a la par con lo último que se subió a github:

```
 ubuntu@bluehost$ git fetch origin # actualizo el index acorde a github
 ubuntu@bluehost$ git reset --hard origin/master # fuerzo el índice al estado en github
 ubuntu@bluehost$ composer install
 ubuntu@bluehost$ sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
```

---

#### Cómo es eso que cada working copy es un respaldo de emergencia?

A diferencia de otros CVS (de entre los cuales SVN es la referencia más inmediata) para GIT el status del repositorio en una revisión XXXX no es simplemente la suma invididual del estado de cada archivo sujeto a control de versiones, y el historial del repo no es tampoco la suma del historial de cada archivo. GIT maneja en cambio un sistema de snapshots del repo como un todo y **no almacena un historial de archivos sino un historial de snapshots**.

Dentro del directorio `.git` existe una estructura comparable a un pequeño sistema de archivos capaz de desacoplar el contenido binario de un elemento de la referencia a éste. y aunque 10 snapshots hagan referencia al mismo archivo su contenido se almacena una sola vez. En una revisión anterior de esta respuesta afirmé equivocadamente que  <strike>Git no guarda archivos sino diferencias entre archivos</strike>. El usuario [eftshift0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/187182/eftshift0) me señaló con toda razón que ello es incorrecto. El contenido íntegro de cada archivo sí se almacena, solo que no se adosa como peso muerto al snapshot como tal.

- al clonar un repo, para poder generar la copia local o copia de trabajo en tu máquina tal que sea autosuficiente y que -por diseño- no considera la necesidad de un servidor centralizado, viene suficiente información como para replicar todos los cambios desde el principio de la historia hasta el presente para los archivos que componen el repo. Esto se cumple únicamente para la rama que estás clonando (99% de las veces, la rama por defecto) de modo que el contenido que sólo existe en otras ramas no viene en el contenido clonado por defecto
- como efecto secundario de lo anterior, esa copia local se acaba de convertir potencialmente en un respaldo de emergencia si explota github y necesitas subir tu repo a otro proveedor. Eso sí, únicamente contiene lo que se haya copiado al clonar o cuando hayas sincronizado manualmente. No es como Dropbox, menos mal.

---

#### Aspectos que no se abordaron

- Seguridad: qué credenciales debiera tener el servidor tal que no me pueda borrar todos mis repos pero tampoco me obligue a digitar la clave en cada deploy?
- Cómo es eso de automatizar el deploy en reacción a un push?
- Para qué sirven los tags?
- Se puede tener más de un remoto?
- Hay herramientas para automatizar el trabajo con varias ramas?
- que pasa si meto un repo en otro repo?
- para qué sirven los git hooks?
- me conviene hostear mi propio servidor git para no pagar github?

Comment: Gracias por esta respuesta magistral la cual tengo que leer más despacio y que merece sin duda una recompensa.

Comment: Debo volver a leer con calma tu respuesta, realmente nunca había trabajado de lleno con `git`, a lo sumo lo había usado como copia de respaldo de algunos proyectos, pero ahora que estoy trabajando la migración de un sitio de Wordpress a una aplicación escrita en Symfony me pareció que usar `git` sería muy útil. Algo que me ayudó mucho fue [lo explicado aquí](https://gist.github.com/Nilpo/8ed5e44be00d6cf21f22). He probado a hacer eso y me está funcionando bien. Quizá uno de mis puntos de confusión fue no partir de un repositorio local, al crear el proyecto Symfony directamente en el hosting.

Comment: Pero cuidado, ese instructivo se refiere al caso en que hosteas tu propio "github de los pobres". Hoy en día nadie haría eso, salvo para usos muy específicos que queden fuera de los planes básicos de github y gitlab, y entre esos dos de verdad hacen casi de todo. Si lo más inmediato es trabajar en tu local y ver el resultado en el servidor, en esta etapa quizá debieras usar las Remote Windows de VSCode y manejarte por sftp+rsync.

Comment: Ok, gracias por la advertencia. La intención no es hostear mi propio Github, me interesa tener el repositorio en github.com, más aún ahora que puedes tener respositorios privados sin pasar a un plan de pago. Yo simplemente estoy buscando una forma práctica de tener una copia de mi sitio asegurada y poder mantenerlo de una forma simple, por lo general modificando código desde mi equipo local y haciendo que esos cambios se reflejen en el sitio.

Comment: No leí todo, pero hay algo que si vi y que hace que casi se me salgan los ojos de las órbitas: **"git no guarda archivos. Guarda diferencias entre versiones de esos archivos."** Eso **no** es cierto. Git, a diferencia de otros manejadores como SVN, no guarda diferencias entre las revisiones. Git guarda los objetos `completos` en su DB.... cont.

Comment: .... Si haces una revisión con un archivo de 1024k. Ese objeto entra completo en la DB y su contenido es accesible a través del id del objeto guardado en la DB.... si le agregas un solo byte al archivo y haces otra revisión, git guarda ese objeto nuevo _completo_ con otro ID (y tambien otra revisión y demás). Git no guarda las diferencias entre esos 2 archivos o esas 2 revisiones. Si le pides hacer un `git diff`, git **en ese momento** calcula las diferencias entre las revisiones/archivos para mostrarlas.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Los-entresijos-internos-de-Git-Los-objetos-Git

Comment: Buena observación. Llevaba muchos años equivocado. Corregiré ese párrafo haciendo hincapié en lo importante, que se mantiene exactamente igual. Espero que los ojos no hayan quedado sueltos

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la siguiente presunción: **Generalmente los repositorios se trabajan desde dos lugares según tengo entendido**. Esto me hace pensar en 2 mantras:

- Un repositorio solo puede tener un ""remoto"
- Ese remoto se llama "origin"

Si piensas que ambas son ciertas, en realidad ahí está el problema porque **ninguna de las 2 es cierta**.

Digamos que organizas tu flujo para tener el repositorio local y el del servidor donde alojas y ya eso lo tienes funcionando bellamente. El problema ahora es "como puedo poner esto tambien en github?"

- Crear el repositorio en github.
- Ve a tu repositorio local y agrega el URL a ese repositorio como un nuevo remoto: `git remote add gh el-url-del-repo` (lo llamé `gh`, pero puedes usar otro nombre).
- Empuja tu rama a ese repo: `git push gh main` (estás empujando la rama main a gh).